# Explaining Ba(OH)2 as a base?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

It is well known fact that Barium Hydroxide is a base. How does the Brønsted-Lowry concept explain $\ce{Ba(OH)2}$  as a base?

Is it that $\ce{Ba(OH)2}$ first accepts a proton then leaves behind $\ce{H2O}$?

Comment: "Is it that Ba(OH)2 first accepts a proton then leaves behind H2O?" You know that's a really interesting statement; if you want to explore mechanisms of acidity, try checking out this thread: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/the-acidity-of-boric-acid

Answer (score 2):

[Barium hydroxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barium_hydroxide) – or more exactly, the hydroxide ion – is a Brønsted-Lowry base, because in aqueous solution, it is completely dissociated into $\ce{Ba^2+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions:

$$\ce{Ba(OH)2 -> Ba^2+ + 2OH-}$$

$\ce{OH-}$ is a proton acceptor, forming $\ce{H2O}$. In aqueous solution, the following reaction takes place:

$$\ce{OH- + H3O+ ->~ 2H2O}$$

Barium hydroxide thus reacts with acids in a neutralization reaction, with water and the barium salt of the respective acid as the products. For example, with hydrochloric acid:

$$\ce{Ba(OH)2 + 2HCl ->~ BaCl2 + 2H2O}$$

Comment: But here it does \n't follow thw basic ideo of bronsted lowry base

Comment: It does if you envision it dissociating first, which it will do in aqueous media.